# How to determine if this function is one-to-one

Tags: functions

I have a question about how to determine if the function is one to one

The question to the problem is, Is $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)= \sqrt{x}+x+2$   one to one?

I know that for a function to be 1 to 1, all x should give the different output. (so if two x have same output, it is not 1 to 1)

I think this function is 1 to 1 because all real positive numbers (domain) is included in real numbers (which include negative numbers, zero,positive numbers), so it is 1 to 1.

Am I correct?

Thanks in advnace!

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need the definition of one-to-one. You say that all $x$ should give a different output. Another way of ensuring this condition is to consider the situation where for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}, f(a) = f(b)$. Then if this situation happens, $a$ better be equal to $b$.

So we have $f(a) = f(b) \implies \sqrt{a} + a + 2 = \sqrt{b} + b + 2$, for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R^+}$. Now our goal is to show $a=b$. It's just an algebra problem.

So $\sqrt{a} + a = \sqrt{b} + b \implies a + a\sqrt{a} + a^2 = b + b\sqrt{b} + b^2$ by squaring both sides.

Then $a(1+\sqrt{a} + a) = b(1+\sqrt{b} + b) \implies a(1+\sqrt{a} + a) = b(1+\sqrt{a} + a)$, because we already know that $\sqrt{a} + a = \sqrt{b} + b$.

Since $a$ is positive, then we can divide both sides by $(1+\sqrt{a} + a)$, and so we have $a=b$.

So yes, the function is one-to-one.

Comment: Simpler, maybe:$$\sqrt a+a=\sqrt b+b\quad\Rightarrow\quad(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)(1+\sqrt a+\sqrt b)=0\ ,$$and the second factor can't be zero.

Comment: thanks! i just have one more question which might sound silly but how did you square both side and get a+a sqr(a)+ a^2=b+b sqr(b)+b^2??

Comment: @wiuwiu You are allowed to square both sides of an equality. If $f(x) = x^2$ is the "squaring" function, then $$a=b \implies f(a)=f(b) \implies a^2=b^2$$.

And yes, you can use $x_1$ and $x_2$. They are just variables. They can be any symbol!

Answer (score 0):

For the function f:{x>0} -> R, if you want to check injectivity (1 to 1), a common approach is to suppose that f maps two things, say $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^+$ to the same value $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, working through it, you will find out that $x_1=x_2$ in which the function is 1 to 1. Hope that will help! (without giving a full solution or answer)

Comment: Your post contains something of an error (in common with the OP) in that injectivity is only half of the defintion of a one-to-one function.  The one-to-one functions are onto as well as injective (1-1).

Answer (score 0):

If
$f(x)= \sqrt{x}+x+2$,
$f'(x)
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+1
> 0
$
for
$x > 0$
so
$f$ is $1-1$.